# How to speed up MySQL query: order by count

Tags: mysql, performance, tags, aggregate

I have tried everything I could think of to speed up this query, but it still takes about 2.5 seconds.

The table is images_tags (~4 Million Rows):
Here is the table EXPLAIN:

```
Field       Type               Null     Key     Default
image_ids   int(7) unsigned    NO       PRI     NULL
tags_id     int(7) unsigned    NO       PRI     NULL
```

Here are the Indexes:

```
Table         Non_unique  Key_name      Seq_in_index  Column_name  Collation  Cardinality  Sub_part  Packed  Null  Index_type
images_tags   0           PRIMARY       1             image_ids    A          NULL         NULL      NULL          BTREE
images_tags   0           PRIMARY       2             tags_id      A          4408605      NULL      NULL          BTREE
images_tags   1           image_ids     1             image_ids    A          734767       NULL      NULL          BTREE
```

And here is the query:

```
select image_ids
from images_tags
where tags_id in (1, 2, 21, 846, 3175, 4290, 6591, 9357, 9594, 14289, 43364, 135019, 151295, 208803, 704452)
group by image_ids
order by count(*) desc
limit 10
```

And here is the query EXPLAIN:

```
select_type  table        type   possible_keys  key                 key_len  ref   rows     Extra
SIMPLE       vids_x_tags  index  join_tags_id   join_vids_id_unique  8       NULL  4408605  Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

The goal is to get the 10 images that match those tags the most.
I have tried messing around with these variables with little to no improvement:

- max_heap_table_size
- tmp_table_size
- myisam_sort_buffer_size
- read_buffer_size
- sort_buffer_size
- read_rnd_buffer_size
- net_buffer_length
- preload_buffer_size
- key_buffer_size

Is there any way to speed up this query considerably? There are about 700K images and it's always growing, so I wouldn't want to cache the result for more than a day or 2, and it has to be done for each image, so re-caching that many queries would be impossible.

Comment: `count(*)`? Sure about this? Shouldn't it be `count(image_ids)`?

Comment: @Burhan: Since the `image_ids` has no nulls, that's the same thing.

Comment: Please add the EXPLAIN output.

Comment: `There are about 700K images and it's always growing, so I wouldn't want to cache the result for more than a day or 2 and re-caching that many results would be impossible.` - aren't you only going to have 10 results in the cache? If the currency of the information is not critical; you could generate the cache at downtime store the 10 ids and retrieve them only in the display.

Comment: I would try adding a compound index on `(tags_id, image_ids)` - but the efficiency of it (if used) will depend on data distribution. And the `(image_ids)` index is redundant, you can remove it.

Comment: @ypercube added query EXPLAIN. Also, wouldn't a compound index be redundant since the primary key is already a compound index of both fields?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I would have to run this query 700K times everyday to re-cache everything

Comment: Can you tell us what is the result of `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT image_ids) FROM images_tags WHERE tags_id IN (1, 2, 21, 846, 3175, 4290, 6591, 9357, 9594, 14289, 43364, 135019, 151295, 208803, 704452) ;`

Comment: @ricka: It's not redundant because the fields are in reverse order.

Comment: @ricka - 700K times _every day_? Why? You need to generate top 10; you can generate it _once_ by running the query _once_ per day, and then store the results. That is your top 10. Unless I missed something about generating top 10 images for tags.

Comment: @ypercube The result of that query is: 304538

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I apologize, I left out important info. This query gets the 10 most related images to 1 individual image (by cross-referencing it's tags, seeing how many they have it common). So I would have to re-cache every image every day. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

In this kind of link (junction, many-to-many) tables, it's almost always useful to have two compound indices, on both `(a, b)` and `(b, a)`. You have only one of them (the primary index) and not the other.

And if there are no other columns in the table, you don't need any other index at all.

So, you should add the `(tags_id, image_ids)` index and remove the `(image_ids)` one which is redundant:

```
ALTER TABLE images_tags
  DROP INDEX image_ids,
  ADD INDEX tag_image_IDX           -- choose a name for the index
    (tags_id, image_ids) ;
```

The efficiency of the index regarding the specific query depends on a lot of factors and mainly on the distribution of images and tags (how popular are the 15 tags you have in the `IN` list?)

Comment: I ran that code and it seemed to have shaved off about 100ms. Without the limit, 304538 rows are returned.

Answer (score 1):

In the `EXPLAIN` output from your query, you see that the `key` column does not match any item from the `possible_keys` list. This means that although the data was fetched from the index (which in many cases is smaller than the actual table, as it spans fewer columns), the engine still had to traverse all rows.

If your want to properly use an index to speed up this query, you should add one with the tag as its *first* (and probably only) component.

By the way, the index on `image_ids` only is of little use, as the primary key can be used to provide that information just as well. In general, an index over multiple rows can be used to speed up queries which provide explicit values (or ranges) for either all of these columns, or a continuous set of columns starting at the first. In other words, a two-column index will serve like a single column index for its first column as well, but won't be much use for its second column all by itself, which is what you have here.

As an alternative to adding a key on `tags_id` and dropping the key on `image_ids`, you could keep the key on `image_ids` as it is, and reverse the order of columns for the primary key. Then the primary key could be used to answer tag-only queries as well. If you query the table more often by tag than by image, then I'd suggest this approach.